# how can I change my primary VGA from intel to Gforce in lenovo z510?

Tags: display

I have Ideapad z510 and I want to use 3D vision photo viewer and it needs to change display adapter to gforce as a primary one. so do know any solution?
than Q so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

See the lenovo support site http://support.lenovo.com/ch/de/documents/ht071102
also may depend on whether your power is plugged in or you're running on battery.